# Using Scrapy and send_keys on the following input field

Tags: python, selenium, input, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I am trying to focus on the email input on twitter.com/login and send_keys('foo'), however I am having no luck.  Can someone tell me why my implementation is wrong:

```
import time

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from selenium import webdriver 

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "new"
    allowed_domains = ["twitter.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.twitter.com/login"]

    def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(1)

    #print response.body
    username = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('email-input')
    username.click()
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys('foo')


    #self.driver.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Also, I get the following error when I attempt this:

> 2015-08-22 15:44:09-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
>   2015-08-22 15:44:10-0500 [new] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to https://twitter.com/login> from https://www.twitter.com/login>
>   2015-08-22 15:44:10-0500 [new] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://twitter.com/login> (referer: None)
>   2015-08-22 15:44:22-0500 [new] ERROR: Spider error processing https://twitter.com/login> (referer: None)
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
>           self.runUntilCurrent()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
>           call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
>           self._startRunCallbacks(result)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
>           self._runCallbacks()
>       ---  ---
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
>           current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>         File "/home/tyrick/Documents/twitter_followers/twitter_followers/spiders/newUsers.py", line 22, in parse
>           username.click()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 65, in click
>           self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
>           return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>       Stacktrace:
>           at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpHPD9xT/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8959:12)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpHPD9xT/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11618:15)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpHPD9xT/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:11)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpHPD9xT/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
>           at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpHPD9xT/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, there are *multiple elements with `email-input` class*, and the first one, that is actually located, is invisible. You need the one in the page container:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#page-container .email-input")
```